# Finding the root of a function in an interval using maxima

Tags: real-analysis, roots, maxima-minima, maxima-software

I'm trying to find the roots of the function $f:[-2\pi,2\pi] \to [-1,1]$, with  $f(x)=\sin(x)/2$ using maxima. Intuitively I know that the solutions are; $x = -2\pi, x=0$ and $x=2\pi$. I started by doing the following:

```
f(x):= sin(x)/2$

solve(f(x) = 0)
```

But I got the following error message:

```
solve: using arc-trig functions to get a solution.
Some solutions will be lost.
(%o27)  [x=0]
```

Then, I tried using the following command specifying the interval and got:

```
find_root(f(x), -2*%pi, 2*%pi)
(%028) 0.0
```

And this only returned me $x = 0$ as well. How can I do this?

Comment: It is also $0$ for $x=\pm\pi$.

Comment: By the way, $f([- 2 \pi, 2 \pi]) = [-1/2, 1/2]$.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44872011/1187415